# How to align multiple vertices on face mesh

Tags: modeling

I want to align the vertices shown in the example for they form a rectangle. I tried selecting them all, and with S, Z, 0, they collapsed making a mess. So then I did each line individually ( S, Z, 0) so I can get the rectangle result. So is there a method which I can use to achieve this aligning them all at once?

[image: ll]

Comment: You could use the shear tool, but I’m not sure how to get precise results in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a plane with subdivision and use shrinkwrap on the aimed object. Then merge them and remove colliding faces and connect vertices around that rectangle.